# Strange line buffering behaviour in Tcl 8.6?

Tags: tcl

EDIT: Original example and alternative solution framework modified for clarity.

The line buffering behaviour might behave differently than expected in Tcl 8.6. The following code blocks without any output, unless the "chan close" line is uncommented:

```
set data {one two four}
set stream [open |[list cat -n] r+]
chan configure $stream -buffering line

chan puts $stream "$data\n"
chan puts $stream "\n"
chan flush $stream
#chan close $stream write
set out [chan read $stream]
puts "output: $out"
chan close $stream
```

So this simplistic solution does not work for interactive I/O, and this might be related to synchronization problems at both ends of the pipe.

Using a channel event structure (e.g., based on http://www.beedub.com/book/2nd/event.doc.html), seems to be preferable:

```
proc chanReader { pipe } {

   global extState

   while 1 {
      set len [chan gets $pipe line]
      if { $len > 0 } {
         puts "<< $line."
         continue
      } else {
         if { [chan blocked $pipe] } {
            set extState 1
            return
         } elseif { [chan eof $pipe] } {
            set extState 2
            return
         }
      }
   }
}


set data {one two foure}
set timeout 5000

#set stream [open [list | cat -n] r+]
#set stream [open [list | ispell -a] r+]
set stream [open [list | tr a-z A-Z] r+]
#set stream [open [list | fmt -] r+]
chan configure $stream -blocking 0 -buffering line
set extState 0
chan event $stream readable [list chanReader $stream]

foreach word $data {
   puts "> $word\n"
   chan puts $stream "$word\n"
   chan flush $stream
   #chan close $stream write
   set aID [after $timeout {set extState 3}]
   vwait extState
   if { $extState == 1 } {
      # Got regular output.
      after cancel $aID
      puts "Cancel $aID."
      continue
   } elseif { $extState == 2 } {
      puts "External program closed."
      chan close $stream
      exit 2
   } elseif { $extState == 3 } {
      puts "Timeout."
      chan close $stream
      exit 3
   }
}

puts "End of task."
chan close $stream
exit 0
```

This code fragment works with the "cat -n" and "ispell -a" external programs (commented lines), but still fails with other external programs. For instance it does not work with the "tr a-z A-Z" and "fmt" examples above.

If the line "chan close $stream write" above is uncommented, we receive output from the external program, but this terminates the interaction with it. How to reliably connect (interactively) to these external programs?

Comment: So, why is the 'chan close $stream write' command commented out? I think you have been experimenting and have more to tell us.

Comment: And the `cat` command is going to have input and output buffering.  Unless you can control the behavior of both ends of the pipeline, I don't think anything can be guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, I want to use this code fragment for successive read / write operations from an external program, with a line buffered channel (pipe). I do not want to write everything at once, close the channel and finally read from the external program. I would prefer to keep the pipe open, and read from it as needed. Hence my question

Comment: You could try using `chan pipe` on 8.6 and see if that changes anything, but the semantics of 8.6 in this area are supposed to be the same as previous versions (except those couldn't half-close anything).

Comment: You should probably note that in your solution, within the Reader proc you set a local variable "done", but the main execution thread is vwait'ing on a *global* variable "done".  Within Reader, you either want to add a line "global done" or change the reference to "set ::done 1" to force the global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the core issue here is that there's two sources of buffering going on, and Tcl only has control over one of them. But both stem from the fact that virtually all *output*, when not going to an “interactive” destination (i.e., a terminal), is buffered. There's basically a call in the C standard library that determines this and enables the buffering feature, and Tcl follows that rule too (despite using its entirely independent I/O library). Doing this *massively* speeds up non-interactive pipeline processing, but means that if you're expecting to see every byte output exactly at the point when the program thinks it is writing it, you're going to be disappointed.

Of course, programs can switch this buffering off if they want. In Tcl, this is done by `fconfigure $channel -buffering none` (or `line` for line-oriented buffering). In `cat`, the `-n` option makes it do the equivalent (calling `setvbuf()` in C) and `ispell` is probably doing the same. But *most programs don't*. Some instead call `fflush()` from time to time; that works too, but is also a minority practice. So with a bidirectional pipeline such as you're using, you can easily force the side where you feed into it from Tcl not buffer, but you *can't* usually get the other side to do the same.

There is a workaround: run the subprocess with Expect. That puts a fake terminal between Tcl and the subprocess (instead of a pipe) and tricks it into thinking it is talking direct to the user. But the consequence of this is that you have to substantially rewrite your Tcl program and you gain a dependency on a (very fine!) external package.